# Using arbitrary owning pointer without templating

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I would like to pass (shared) ownership of an object to a function `foo::bar`.
The thing is I do not care, whether the ownership is exclusive or shared.
I see `class foo` as an interface where I do not want to care about the ownership details.
All I care about is that I can secure the lifetime of the passed smart pointer beyond the return of `foo::bar`.

Now I could write

```
class foo {
  void bar( std::shared_ptr<blub> );
  void bar( std::unique_ptr<blub> );
};
```

but this is unelegant in times where we have accumulated several smart pointer variants.
And writing an overload for every variant is quite cumbersome, especially if I want to use this scheme multiple times in my code.

Now I also do not want `foo` to be templated, for the obvious template complexities.

The simplest I can come up with would be a smart pointer wrapper

```
template <typename T>
class owning_ptr {
  // Sorts out the largest type so we can allocate enough space
  typedef largest<std::shared_ptr<T>, std::unique_ptr<T>, myptr<T>>::type big_type;
  typedef std::aligned_storage <sizeof(big_type), std::alignment_of<big_type>::value>::type buffer_type;
  buffer_type _internal;
  int _type;
};
```

which is a bit inefficient. Is there a better way to construct the wrapper?

In the end I would really like to have the signature:

```
class foo {
  void bar( owning_ptr<blub> );
};
```

Comment: are templates an option?

Comment: @stefan for everything except `foo`.

Comment: you only need to use templates for `bar` ;-)

Comment: @stefan Sure. The question still remains, how does one manage arbitrary owning pointers elegantly. :P

Comment: You can construct a `std::shared_ptr` from a `std::unique_ptr` anyway (needs a move but that is required anyway). `std::shared_ptr` can also hold a pointer that is different from the owned pointer so create a shared pointer to your custom pointer (or a copy thereof) and return another constructed from that shared pointer and the raw pointer pointed to your custom owning pointer. The wrapping into a shared pointer can be done an a small wrapper function or for convenience as a conversion operator in your owning pointers.

Comment: @LCIDFire I understand your problem now. Do you need many different `blubb` objects so that it really matters to have `AnyPtrType<blubb>`? I don't think this is feasible. Generally speaking I would recommend not using pointers at all. In most cases you just eliminate the possibility for the compiler to optimize. However you'll better know if you really need a ptr, I know there are indeed reasons to have them ;-)

Comment: Can you move the function call?
Considering something along the lines of ...
`template< typename T > void call_bar(foo& f, T t) { f.bar(t.get()); }`

Comment: or `template< typename T > struct call_bar { void call(foo& f, T t) { f.bar(t.get()); } };`

Answer (score 0):

**Note: There's an interesting EDIT at the bottom**

If you don't want to parameterize or overload on the owning pointer type, you're probably best off taking a `shared_ptr<>` and forcing a conversion for `unique_ptr<>`.  Any non-template solution I can think of would have at least the same amount of overhead as a `shared_ptr`, most requiring a polymorphic call, a free-store allocation, or both.

You might be able to automate the conversion from `shared_ptr` by taking some type of proxy converter, which should allow you to take either a `unique_ptr` R-value or a `shared_ptr` without a cast or explicit conversion (other than `move()`) and extract a usable `shared_ptr` to store in your instance.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

// Take an instance of gimme_owned_ptr<T> to save off a shared_ptr<T>
// from either a shared_ptr or unique_ptr.
template<typename T>
struct gimme_owned_ptr {
    // Make the two constructors templates so we can accept
    // any convertible owning pointer:
    template<typename S>
    gimme_owned_ptr( unique_ptr<S> p )
        : p_( shared_ptr<S>( move(p) ) )
    { }
    template<typename S>
    gimme_owned_ptr( shared_ptr<S> p )
        : p_( p )
    { }
    shared_ptr<T> get() const {
        return p_;
    }
private:
    shared_ptr<T> p_;
};

struct Foo {
    void operator()() const { v_call(); }
    virtual ~Foo() { }
private:
    virtual void v_call() const = 0;
};

struct Bar {
    Bar( gimme_owned_ptr<Foo const> const &gop )
        : foo_( gop.get() )
    { }
    void operator()() const { (*foo_)(); }
private:
    shared_ptr<Foo const> foo_;
};

struct Baz : Foo {
private:
    virtual void v_call() const { cout << "Baz()()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    unique_ptr<Baz> upf( new Baz() );
    shared_ptr<Baz> spf( new Baz() );

    Bar upb( move( upf ) );
    Bar spb( spf );

    upb();
    spb();
}
```

Yes, this solution does use templates, but only for the `gimme_owned_ptr` utility class template, and only for re-use and conversion.  Your own class (`Bar` in this case) wouldn't need to be a template, nor would you need to re-implement `gimme_owned_ptr` to use it with another type.

**======== EDIT ========**

I just checked, and the built-in conversion from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` essentially does everything the `gimme_owned_ptr` class I wrote above.  If the class takes a type of `shared_ptr<T>`, passing a `move(unique_ptr<S>)` will result in a workable conversion.  So, all you really need is to take a `shared_ptr` and the only thing the user should have to do is call `move()` on `unique_ptr`s (which they should be doing anyway).  The only reason to use something like `gimme_owned_ptr` would be to accept a different mixture of pointers or accept them in a different way.  (For example, you could make the `move()` unnecessary by taking a `unique_ptr<S>&` and calling `move()` internally, but this is probably a bad idea as it will silently seize ownership.)